# SSMS keeps using NTLM rather than Kerberos on one computer

Tags: sql-server, ssms, kerberos, ntlm

On my computer SQL Server Management Studio is using NTLM rather than Kerberos as expected. Which is causing issues accessing linked servers.

I wouldn't think this would be a very hard issue to fix but there are a few weird points that prompted me to post here

1. If I log into another computer and launch SSMS I have kerberos
2. If someone else logs into my computer the auth_type is NTLM
3. I do get a Kerb ticket
4. My AD admin is assuring me that my user settings are correct and I match identically someone else that I know is not having this issue
5. My data architect suggested having me computer re-imaged to see if some software that I installed is making that happen but that did not help the issue if I only install SSMS on top of the fresh image.
6. I am currently using SSMS 2016

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Ooh… that's tough. How are you connecting to SQL Server? Specifically, what does `select net_transport from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id = @@spid` return?

Comment: I was hoping it would be that easy but I am connecting through TCP

Comment: I am leaning towards it being a config issue on your machine (as evidenced by points 1 & 2 above). Now it's a matter of figuring out what the difference is. I wouldn't do the nuke and pave as that's a big hammer and it doesn't guarantee that the issue would be solved since you don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks Ben,They did Nuke and rebuilt my laptop. It should be the same build as one of my co-works for whom this works